# how to split and wrap mixed content

Tags: xslt

Given the source xml :

```
<margetekst>
    Article 36<em>bis</em>
    Article 40
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test 1
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test 2a
    test 2b
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test <em>3a</em>
    test 3b
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test <em>4</em>a and some more text
    test <em>4</em>b
</margetekst>
```

I need the following result :

```
<margetekst>
    <div>Article 36<em>bis</em></div>
    <div>Article 40</div>
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    <div>test 1</div>
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    <div>test 2a</div>
    <div>test 2b</div>
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    <div>test <em>3a</em></div>
    <div>test 3b</div>
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    <div>test <em>4</em>a and some more text</div>
    <div>test <em>4</em>b</div>
</margetekst>
```

I have found on this site a solution to split text on the linebreaks, and this works fine when the content of `<margetekst>` is just a string, but not in mixed content (result is: `<div>Article 36</div><em>bis</em><div>...</div>`). This is the code I currently use :

```
<xsl:template match="margetekst/text()" mode="paragraafstijlen">
    <xsl:call-template name="div_insert">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" name="div_insert">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))">
            <div><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '&#xA;')"/></div>
            <xsl:call-template name="div_insert">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9?

Comment: yes, I am currently using saxon9he

Answer (score 2):

With your edited requirements I think it is better to do a two pass transformation where we first transform any line break characters in text nodes into an element (I have used an 'lb' element) to then group on those elements using `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="lb"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="margetekst">
  <margetekst>
    <xsl:variable name="lbs">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="lb-char-to-lb-el"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$lbs/node()" group-starting-with="lb">
        <xsl:if test="not(self::lb and count(current-group()) eq 1)">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
            </div>                
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </margetekst>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '&#10;')]" mode="lb-char-to-lb-el">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\n">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
          <lb/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample is at http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9Q, it transforms

```
<root>
<margetekst>
    Article 36<em>bis</em>
    Article 40
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test 1
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test 2a
    test 2b
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test <em>3a</em>
    test 3b
</margetekst>
<margetekst>
    test <em>4</em>a and some more text
    test <em>4</em>b
</margetekst>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
   <margetekst>
      <div>Article 36<em>bis</em></div>
      <div>Article 40</div>
   </margetekst>
   <margetekst>
      <div>test 1</div>
   </margetekst>
   <margetekst>
      <div>test 2a</div>
      <div>test 2b</div>
   </margetekst>
   <margetekst>
      <div>test<em>3a</em></div>
      <div>test 3b</div>
   </margetekst>
   <margetekst>
      <div>test<em>4</em>a and some more text
      </div>
      <div>test<em>4</em>b
      </div>
   </margetekst>
</root>
```

which I think has all the `div` wrappers as required.

Comment: @ChrisV, please edit your question and provide the new input samples and wanted results in the question, properly marked up as code samples, then it is easier to read them and understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ChrisV, I have edited the answer and provided a new approach that should handle your requirements better. It is still using `for-each-group group-starting-with`, but transforms line break characters in a first pass into `lb` elements, to be better able to use the grouping construct.